# Interacting with the wordpress api with an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I have built an asp.net application from which I would like to post blog entries to wordpress, using the wordpress API.  Thus far I have been unable to find any good tutorials or walkthroughs to do so.  How might I use the wordpress API to upload blog content via an asp.net application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you should use the xml-rpc (probably need to enable on your server under administration area). [xml-rpc](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support). However, actual implementation details I am not positive on. Hopefully this gives you a start.

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp